# Remove a mercurial repository - some files 'missing' from directory

Tags: mercurial, undo

I got all the fonts from the Google font project on my computer via Terminal by using:

```
hg clone someURL;
```

I would like to delete it all from my computer. I've seen the following code suggested in another thread:

```
rm -r .hg
```

I'm uncertain what the .hg refers to though. There are less than 20 fonts in the 'googlefontdirectory' folder, even though I can use many more Google fonts in various apps. I'm concerned that simply deleting the 'googlefontdirectory' folder won't get rid of everything, since most of the fonts don't seem to be there. What is the best way to delete/remove all fonts that came with the 'hg clone'?

Answer (score 0):

**ALL** files in repo, cloned by `hg clone` command placed inside one directory, which is Working Copy and local repository in .hg subdir. `rm -r .hg` doesn't remove all cloned data, only repository *without working copy*

> hg help clone
>
> ...
>
> Create a copy of an existing repository in a new directory.
>
> If no destination directory name is specified, it defaults to the
>   basename of the source.

**Added results of repo-clone**

> There are less than 20 fonts in the 'googlefontdirectory' folder

Really?!

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/
...
added 3056 changesets with 60182 changes to 46816 files (+1 heads)
updating to branch default
27215 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

dir /S *.ttf
...
Total Files Listed:
            1295 File(s)    201 270 824 bytes
```

Comment: The 'googlefontdirectory' has 20 items - 19 font folders and 1 readme file. I just did a 'hg pull' and 'hg update' and the results are:                                                          'pulling from https://googlefontdirectory.googlecode.com/hg/
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 26 changesets with 188 changes to 184 files
...
184 files updated, 0 files merged, 9 files removed, 0 files unresolved'

Comment: @user1804660 - you can `hg log -r tip` and see, where are you. at least **now** I see one head c3eeaea3e3b5 from yesterday. `hg incoming` also can shed some light on state of your repo - I'm afraid you have incomplete pull